# Multiple COUNT in 1 SQLITE Query

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

Using SQLite.

```
   SELECT c.*,
          COUNT(m.course_id) AS "meeting_count",
          COUNT(r.meeting_id) AS "race_count"
     FROM course c
LEFT JOIN meeting m ON m.course_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN race r ON r.meeting_id = m.id
 GROUP BY c.id
```

Course has meetings has races.

Trying to select the correct count for course meetings and course races. The problem is the above query is returning the same count for "meeting_count" as "race_count". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: COUNT counts the number of non-NULL values in the column specified - without example data, how are we to know why you're getting identical counts, or if this is bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding DISTINCT like `COUNT(DISTINCT m.course_id)`

Comment: seems to do the trick :) need to expand my data past 1 meeting though, to make sure it calculates that correctly.